# Accessing QTabWidget's widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTabWidget with 2 tabs and I promoted each to 2 custom widgets. 
Those widgets have functions "typeName()" and "baseName()", but I cannot access those functions with "QTabwidget->currentWidget()".

```
        std::string type = ui->tabWidget->currentWidget()->typeName().toUtf8().constData();
        std::string base = ui->tabWidget->currentWidget()->baseName().toUtf8().constData();
```

This throws me an error "it has no member named ..."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an explicit (down) cast to the particular type in the tab. The functions are not present in base class QWidget which is returned by currentWidget().

```
std::string type = dynamic_cast<CustomType*>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget())->typeName().toUtf8().constData();
```

Comment: I have promoted tab to a custom widget, shouldn't it return the promoted class?

Comment: @khajvah : It always returns a pointer to QWidget, i.e. QWidget* (pointer to base class).

Comment: So, promoting a widget to QTabWidget does nothing more than displaying  it when tab is chosen? BTW, it worked, thanks :)

Comment: @khajvah : This is how polymorphism works. The return of type the function in QTabWidget is totally unchanged. BTW: I guess my answer could be accepted then?